# Retrieve the object by passing the ID in Angular navigation

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular and learning angular by my own. I have doubt regarding passing of data from one component to another.

In my below code i'm passing ID using click method I have a sample JSON object which contains array of objects. Let's assume that I have 3 objects with different ID and I'm looping the data using `*ngFor`. Now using `(click)` method i'm passing my `ID` as below

```
goToWorkOrderDetails(id): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/work-orders/work-order-details', { id }]);
 }
```

In my next page I'm retrieving the `ID` using

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params)=> this.user.id= this.params['id'])
```

Is there any way to retrieve the complete objection containing that `id`?

Comment: store the data in a common service and access the value from the new component, we can use the data parameter also to send via URL, but the data will be shown in the URL

Comment: @NarenMurali any example leads to check this?  Do I need to subscribe the data from the service using this ID in my new component?

Comment: refer [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-navigate-3yvgqo?file=app/app.router.ts)

Answer (score -1):

You can use angular service. Save your object there and retrieve it on your new component. If you want to send them via url you can use **NavigationExtras**.

**Home Component**

```
import {Router,NavigationExtras} from '@angular/router';

const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  state: {
   id:id,
   name: name,
   ....other properties of your object here
 }
};
this.router.navigate(['/work-orders/work-order-details'], navigationExtras);
```

**newComponent**

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
   const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
   const state = navigation.extras.state as {
    id: string,//or whatever you want
    name: string,
   };
console.log("id: " + state.id ",name:" + state.name)
}
```

Comment: Let's assume that I have an array of 5 different objects. And I'm getting that from backend API. Then How can I achieve this using navigationExtras. Using ngfor and on (click) send navigationExtras? and what's the best practice?

Comment: The best practice to pass data is using service!But if these components are parent and child or siblings there more ways to transfer data. You can read [this useful article](https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

Comment: But I Just wanna send only Id through params and retrieve the data in next page using that id. How can I do that?

Comment: Create a service and an array on your service and save the objects from your API there.On your new component, with the id from url params find this object on your service's array and display it

Comment: @saimanoj i made an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xptegk with service and display data with id only! You can change it for your needs.